# md5sum returns different values with "same" strings

Tags: hash, terminal

md5sum function returns different values in the same string 
In this case

```
>echo -n Bob | md5sum 
 2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b
```

But in this other case .

```
>md5sum <<< Bob 
a2eae7400008e77790c3272f754a14db
```

What happened here? Some advices?

Comment: The output is the same actually. What do you mean exactly? Did you execute that code?

Comment: I did execute these code because I wanted check the result of md5 function, I tested 
mysql function md5(). 
I have a mistake in my written in the first code the result is 
2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b
in the second is 
a2eae7400008e77790c3272f754a14db

Comment: Does my answer not help ?

Comment: I used this statement SELECT md5("Bob"); that returns the following result '2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b'
After I executed echo Bob | md5sum with the following result 'a2eae7400008e77790c3272f754a14db' and 
this md5sum<<Bob returns the same result 'a2eae7400008e77790c3272f754a14db'
although when executed echo -n Bob | md5sum  <<< Bob with the following result "2fc1c0beb992cd7096975cfebf9d5c3b"


Why are they give me different results?

Comment: That is not the question. Sorry, but you were asking for the difference of two instructions in the shell. Modify your question if you think you need to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The here string includes an implicit newline character (`0x0a` in hexadecimal). Compare

```
$ echo -n Bob | hexdump
0000000 42 6f 62
0000003
```

with

```
$ hexdump <<< "Bob"
0000000 42 6f 62 0a
0000004
```

You are actually computing the MD5 checksum for two different strings, hence the difference in output. If you don't suppress the newline from the output of `echo`, you get the same result as with the here string:

```
$ echo Bob | md5
a2eae7400008e77790c3272f754a14db
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is the same in your example actually. However, 
remove the option `-n` from the first example:

```
echo Bob | md5sum
```